# android activity onResume and onPause is called so many time

Tags: android, events, android-activity

I create one application when phone come from deep sleep mode in my activity onResume and onPause method is called so many times.
I implemented the following method of activity:
`onSaveInstanceState`, `onRestoreInstanceState`, `onPause`, `onResume`, `onCreate`, onStart, `onRestart`, `onStop` and `onDestroy` method and my activity configuration is

```
 <activity
            android:name=".ScreenActivity"  
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"  
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"                            
            >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
  </activity>
```

Here is My log information

```
2012_10_16   11:58:8:80 PM: ScreenActivity.onResume:  Activity interacting with user
2012_10_16   11:58:8:119 PM: ScreenActivity.onSaveInstanceState:  onSaveInstanceState method called
2012_10_16   11:58:8:119 PM: ScreenActivity.onPause:  current activity got paused
2012_10_16   11:58:8:380 PM: ScreenActivity.onResume:  Activity interacting with user
2012_10_16   11:58:8:409 PM: ScreenActivity.onSaveInstanceState:  onSaveInstanceState method called
2012_10_16   11:58:8:411 PM: ScreenActivity.onPause:  current activity got paused
2012_10_16   11:58:8:434 PM: ScreenActivity.onResume:  Activity interacting with user
2012_10_16   11:58:8:493 PM: ScreenActivity.onSaveInstanceState:  onSaveInstanceState method called
2012_10_16   11:58:8:497 PM: ScreenActivity.onPause:  current activity got paused
2012_10_16   11:58:10:885 PM: ScreenActivity.onResume:  Activity interacting with user
2012_10_16   11:58:10:914 PM: ScreenActivity.onSaveInstanceState:  onSaveInstanceState method called
2012_10_16   11:58:10:916 PM: ScreenActivity.onPause:  current activity got paused
2012_10_16   11:58:10:999 PM: ScreenActivity.onResume:  Activity interacting with user
2012_10_16   11:58:11:32 PM: ScreenActivity.onSaveInstanceState:  onSaveInstanceState method called
```

Please provide help

Comment: Please format your question. My suggestion go through lifecycle of activity @ http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: "Please provide help" > Please provide code ...

Comment: Sometime i get this issue.If u see the log  method call is done milliseconds.I have provide empty implantation of onResume and onPause method.

Comment: What other information is in the logcat during the same period of time? Are there other messages from other applications?

Comment: There is no other information.

Comment: Can any one tell how i will upload code